# meaning of carnival diver

Tags: expressions, metaphors

Who knows what a carnival diver is? I heard it in the song "On a Tuesday in Amsterdam" by Counting Crows and I came across two references on the internet. What can it be?

Comment: I checked several song lyrics sites. Almost all say the word is _driver_, not _diver_. The latter was only at 1 of the 8 sites I checked.

Comment: I've seen the term once or twice and assumed it to mean a person who dives from a high platform into a small tub of water.  Probably more often done in a circus than a "carnival" (as the term is used in the US), and likely rare in either since the middle of the last century.  Looking at the lyric online I feel that interpretation is reasonably consistent.  Google "circus diver" and you will see this meaning represented.  This image portrays this: https://img1.etsystatic.com/003/0/5174057/il_570xN.368873109_rup1.jpg

Comment: @Barmer: song lyrics sites are really bad. If the first person to transcribe the lyrics gets them wrong, nearly everybody else copies them. And then 90% of the lyrics sites are wrong. I hear *"carnival diver"*. And *"carnival driver"* doesn't make any more sense than *"carnival diver"*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual thing, however there are two likely explanations for the poetic use of this phrase.

As evidenced by later lyrics in the song ("she is the film of the book of the story of the smell of her hair"), the narrator of the song clearly does not actually remember the details of this woman.  It is possible the use of "carnival diver" is similar in that no such profession exists, and the woman's actual profession is not memorable enough for the narrator.

Alternatively, "carnival" is used as the adjective form of something having the festivity (and possibly the brevity) of the celebration of Carnival.  It is possible that she was an actual professional ocean diver who did so at the whim of her own personal desires rather than a schedule, traveling to where she saw fit.